# How to calculate maximum diferences among different number of columns for different variables

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataframe (`df`) with average Current Intensities for two different sites (`A` and `B`) and for different depths (5 meters `C.I.5m`, 12 meters `C.I.12m`, 20 meters `C.I.20m`, 28 meters `C.I.28m` and 35 meters `C.I.35m`) over time. Here I show an example:

```
df<- data.frame(Datetime=c("2018-08-06 00:00:00","2018-08-06 00:00:00","2018-08-06 03:00:00","2018-08-06 03:00:00","2018-08-06 06:00:00","2018-08-06 06:00:00"),
                Site=c("A","B","A","B","A","B"),
                C.I.5m=c(0.1,0.3,0.8,0.2,0.4,0.2),
                C.I.12m=c(0.2,0.1,0.6,0.3,0.2,0.4),
                C.I.20m=c(0.1,0.3,0.7,0.4,0.4,0.2),
                C.I.28m=c(0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.1,0.2),
                C.I.35m=c(0.3,0.5,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1))
df

             Datetime Site C.I.5m C.I.12m C.I.20m C.I.28m C.I.35m
1 2018-08-06 00:00:00    A    0.1     0.2     0.1     0.2     0.3
2 2018-08-06 00:00:00    B    0.3     0.1     0.3     0.3     0.5
3 2018-08-06 03:00:00    A    0.8     0.6     0.7     0.4     0.2
4 2018-08-06 03:00:00    B    0.2     0.3     0.4     0.1     0.3
5 2018-08-06 06:00:00    A    0.4     0.2     0.4     0.1     0.4
6 2018-08-06 06:00:00    B    0.2     0.4     0.2     0.2     0.1
```

I want to calculate how much differ the current intensity among depths (that is, among columns in my dataframe) with different variables. The first variable I call it `MCICC`(`Maximum Current Intensity Change in Column`) and is the maximum difference among the values from the different columns related to the current intensity (`C.I.5m`,`C.I.12m`,`C.I.20m`,`C.I.28m` and `C.I.35m`). Then, another variable called `MCIC10m` that summarizes the difference between `C.I.5m` and `C.I.12m`. Then another one called `MCIC20m` that summarizes the difference between `C.I.12m`, `C.I.20m` and `C.I.28m`. Finally, a variable called `MCIC30m` that summarizes the difference between `C.I.28m` and `C.I.35m`.

I would expect this:

```
> df
             Datetime Site C.I.5m C.I.12m C.I.20m C.I.28m C.I.35m MWCICC MWCIC10 MWCIC20 MWCIC30
1 2018-08-06 00:00:00    A    0.1     0.2     0.1     0.2     0.3    0.2     0.1     0.1     0.1
2 2018-08-06 00:00:00    B    0.3     0.1     0.3     0.3     0.5    0.4     0.2     0.2     0.2
3 2018-08-06 03:00:00    A    0.8     0.6     0.7     0.4     0.2    0.6     0.2     0.3     0.2
4 2018-08-06 03:00:00    B    0.2     0.3     0.4     0.1     0.3    0.3     0.1     0.3     0.2
5 2018-08-06 06:00:00    A    0.4     0.2     0.4     0.1     0.4    0.3     0.2     0.3     0.3
6 2018-08-06 06:00:00    B    0.2     0.4     0.2     0.2     0.1    0.3     0.2     0.2     0.1
```

The tricky point is that each new variable is calculated from a different number of primary columns. `MCICC` takes the 5 depths into account (five columns), `MCIC10` takes 5 and 12 meters depth into account (two columns), `MCIC20` takes 12, 20 and 28 meters depth into account (two columns) and `MCIC30` takes 28 and 35 meters depth into account (three columns).

Does anyone know how to calculate all at once?

Comment: I don't know the difference between pairwise difference and adjacent differences... But, as I say in the last paragraph, each new variable summarizes the difference taking into account different columns. For `MCICC` I want the maximum difference among all the five depths, for `MCIC10` the difference between `C.I.5m` and `C.I.12m`, for `MCIC20` the maximum difference between `C.I.12m`, `C.I.20m` and `C.I.28m`, and for `MCIC30` the difference between `C.I.28m` and `C.I.35m`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `combn` to calculate pairwise differences between different columns

```
f1 <- function(data) {
     do.call(pmax, as.data.frame(abs(combn(data, 2,
             FUN =  function(x) x[, 1]- x[,2]))))
 }
MWCICC <- f1(df[-c(1:2)])
MCIC10m <- f1(df[c("C.I.5m", "C.I.12m")])     
MCIC20m <- f1(df[c("C.I.12m", "C.I.20m", "C.I.28m")]
MCIC30m <- f1(df[c("C.I.28m", "C.I.35m")]

df[c("MWCICC", "MCIC10m", "MCIC20m", "MCIC30m")] <- cbind(MWCICC, 
        MCIC10m,  MCIC20m,  MCIC30m)
```